# Перегрузка операторов С#

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте, подскажите в чем дело ни как не могу понять. Перезагружаю оператор равенства (**==**) и неравенства (**!=**) в классе, запускаю код на выполнение и вылетает StackOverflowException.

В качестве примера, набросал код:

```
public class Test
{
    public string Text;

    public Test() { Text = ""; }

    public override int GetHashCode() 
    {
        return base.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        Test t = obj as Test;

        if (t == null) return false;

        return t.Text == this.Text;
    }

    public static bool operator ==(Test t1, Test t2)
    {
        if (t1 == null || t2 == null) return false;

        return (t1.Text == t2.Text);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Test t1, Test t2)
    {
        if (t1 == null || t2 == null) return false;

        return !(t1.Text == t2.Text);
    }
}
```

Теперь, если написать так:

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test t1 = new Test() {  Text = "123"};
        Test t2 = new Test() { Text = "123" };

        bool b = t1 == t2;

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

То вылетит **StackOverflowException**! Почему вылетает исключение так и не могу понять! Самое, интересное, что если перезагрузить, например **+** и запустить код на выполнение то все будет ОК. Что еще больше добавляет вопросов!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваш StakOverflow вываливается потому что вы рекурсивно вызываете ваш собственный оператор **==**, при этом не предусмотрев возможности выхода из рекурсии:

```
public static bool operator ==(Test t1, Test t2)
{
    // эта строка у вас снова вызовет operator ==(Test t1, Test t2)
    if (t1 == null || t2 == null) 
        return false;

    return (t1.Text == t2.Text);
}
```

В один прекрасный момент стек переполняется, и вы получаете исключение

Comment: Опередили на 6 секунд :-)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! То что нужно. Вроде бы очевидная вещь тут происходит, но так сразу и не сообразишь, что к чему, тем более когда голова помимо этого еще много чем занята!

Answer (score 4):

`t1 == null` — это рекурсивный вызов.

Делайте так:

```
if ((object)t1 == null || (object)t2 == null)
{
    ...
```

---

Кстати, ваша логика не вполне верна: если оба аргумента равны `null`, функция вернёт `false`. Делайте так:

```
public static bool operator ==(Test t1, Test t2)
{
    bool firstNull = (object)t1 == null, secondNull = (object)t2 == null;
    if (firstNull || secondNull)
        return firstNull == secondNull;

    return t1.Text == t2.Text;
}

public static bool operator !=(Test t1, Test t2)
{
    return !(t1 == t2);
}
```

Comment: в очередной раз убеждаюсь, до чего крут решарпер)

Comment: @DreamChild: Я пишу пока без него, отстаю от прогресса. Надо догонять :)

Comment: @VladD искренне советую - воспользуйтесь. Недавно пришлось писать в Xamarin Studuio, для которой его нет, так вот Visual Studio + ReSparper по сравнению с этой IDE - это небо и земля в плане удобства рефакторинга и анализа кода, хотя и вышеупомянутый Xamarin сам по себе вполне неплохая IDE

Comment: @DreamChild: О, Xamarin! И как у них с кроссплатформенной разработкой? Чувствуется, что платформа не родная, или нет? (Мне интересно, я никогда не пробовал.)

---
Обязательно попробую! Думаю, с выходом C#6/Roslyn они станут ещё лучше.

Comment: @VladD про кроссплатформенность пока ничего определенного сказать не могу - я сам с ним работаю всего ничего . Пока могу сказать, что среда не без багов, хотя, по-моему, это болезни роста. Но Visual Studio dj многом удобнее (хотя и гораздо тяжелее)
Что касается Resharper и Roslyn - наверное, да, вы правы, с его выходом он станет еще лучше, но до выхода Roslyn думаю еще не близко, да и Resharper сразу не перепишут

Comment: @DreamChild: я надеюсь, roslyn в этом году выйдет. (Кстати, его код [открыли](http://roslyn.codeplex.com/), знаете?)